# How to remove the first 3 seconds from a mp4 file on android?

Tags: android

I want to remove the first 3 seconds from a mp4 video file on android, how can I do it with Android API?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you read the documentation for VideoView for example? Post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `VideoView` for showing the video, try using below code.

```
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
                {
                    videoView.seekTo(3000);
                }
            });
```